# pyinstaller's exe fails to run

Tags: python, mongodb, pygame, pyinstaller

So I have been working on a battleship game project in pygame and wanted to start recording game results to help with building an AI. Unfortunately when I go through with this command for pyinstaller:

> pyinstaller -D -w -n Battleship -F Gui.py

It goes through and creates the exe with no issue, when I go to launch the exe it throws this error seen in the picture below.

Following that path in the error it seems to be when I call my database script then when I try and import pymongo. If I exclude the database side of my script when I make the exe it runs just find and of course is just missing the database interaction portion.

I am running this through pycharm and it works just fine in this development setting but again when I go to create an exe through pyinstaller it results in the error.

Edit 1: So I have run this now without the -w in cmd window and recieved the following:

```
 C:\Users\14402\SynologyDrive\BattleShip\dist>Battleship.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Gui.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  File "DataBase.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  File "pymongo\__init__.py", line 102, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  File "pymongo\collection.py", line 38, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  File "pymongo\common.py", line 42, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  File "pymongo\compression_support.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  File "snappy\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
  File "snappy\__init__.py", line 11, in _delvewheel_init_patch_0_0_9
  File "os.py", line 1111, in add_dll_directory
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\14402\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI1811162\\python_snappy.libs'
[152752] Failed to execute script 'Gui' due to unhandled exception!
```

Along with this I have checked to see if python-snappy is installed and it is:

```
PS C:\Users\14402\SynologyDrive\BattleShip> pip install python-snappy
Requirement already satisfied: python-snappy in c:\users\14402\synologydrive\battleship\venv\lib\site-packages (0.6.1)
WARNING: Error parsing requirements for pytz: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\14402\\synologydrive\\battleship\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\pytz-2022.2.1.dist-info\\METADATA'
```

Finally I will be going through tomorrow and seeing if I can make a simplified version to see if I can better pinpoint, but from my testing this gets thrown when the exe is starting and hits the import for pymongo.

Comment: Try building your executable as a console application, i.e., drop the `-w`. Then, if you open a command window and navigate to the location of your executable and then type `<your.exe>` the exception will be printed to the console. Please [edit] your question to include a [mre].

Comment: create a [example]

Comment: You *do* have the Snappy library available right?  Is there a warning when PyInstaller creates the archive?

Comment: I was able to get it to work...  I did run into some errors but I wasn't able to reproduce the error python-snappy.lib error  when replying to people make sure you use the @Dragonfire31  but with that persons username

Answer (score -1):

So after Alexander said they were able to open things and run it no problem. I created a new project and pulled over all the code and reimported the libraries and it ran just fine. I must have something hanging over in my previous project in my library that is causing the problem but it is resolved now! Thank you all for your questions and help, first time posting and it was a bit rough.

Comment: glad you figured it out.... Please post some sort of solution in your answer though if you don't want to get downvoted... Answers should be reserved for answers

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).